# Polynomial vector space with linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $Ax(t) = x(t+1)$ for every $x$ in $P_n$; prove that if $D$ is the differentiation operator, then $$1+\frac{D}{1!}+\frac{D^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{D^{n-1}}{n-1!}=A$$
Please, explain to me how to start.

Answer (score 1):

After you have proven that $A$ is linear, it is enough to show equality of the operators on monomials. For that, try the binomial theorem.